# Replace C++ enumeration with protobuf enumeration

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, refactoring, protocol-buffers

In my codebase I have unscoped enumeration without underlying type like the one below:

```
enum EFoo {
    EF_AAA     = 0,
    EF_UNKNOWN = 1,
    EF_BBB     = 2,
    EF_MAX
}
```

I want to make it a protobuf enum so it can be reused in other protobuf messages directly as enum, not as some kind of `int*` field. So I imagine enum declaration in .proto file will be like below:

```
enum EFoo {
     EF_AAA    = 0;
     EF_UKNOWN = 1;
     EF_BBB    = 2;
}
```

And here is a tricky part. Over time there might be added new fields like `EF_CCC = 3`, so I can't declare `EF_MAX` like it was in C++ code because it will break binary compatibility with serialized messages containing fields of type `EFoo`. And `EF_MAX` is used in API all over the code base as sort of unknown value for variables of type `EFoo` and `EF_MAX` is never serialized. However, there is a `EFoo_ARRAYSIZE` of type `int` whose semantic meaning is exactly `EF_MAX`. So I'm thinking about replacing all `EF_MAX` with `EFoo_ARRAYSIZE`, but there is one thing that bothers me, It will require to do a `static_cast<EFoo>(EFoo_ARRAYSIZE)` in some places to avoid compiler warnings and according to the standard it will be considered as undefined behaviour, which may result in nasty optimizations and errors.

And my question is, how can I solve my problem? Or maybe I'm wrong and my solution with replacing all `EF_MAX` with `static_cast<EFoo>(EFoo_ARRAYSIZE)` is safe?

In case it may be important, I'm talking about C++11 standard.

Answer (score 4):

Proto3 forces all enums to be 32-bit by adding two "sentinel" values to the enum with INT_MIN and INT_MAX values:

```
enum Foo {
  Foo_FOO = 0,
  Foo_BAR = 1,
  Foo_Foo_INT_MIN_SENTINEL_DO_NOT_USE_ = ::google::protobuf::kint32min,
  Foo_Foo_INT_MAX_SENTINEL_DO_NOT_USE_ = ::google::protobuf::kint32max
};
```

The effect of this is that the enum type `Foo` will always use a 32-bit integer (or larger) as its representation, therefore you can store any 32-bit value into it using `static_cast`s.

Note that proto2 did NOT do this, therefore it is NOT safe to cast the ARRAYSIZE constant as the enum type in proto2. In particular, in proto2, if you had an enum whose maximum value was 127, it might be represented using an 8-bit signed type. The ARRAYSIZE value would be 128, which would be outside the range of that type -- it might be treated as -128. Or worse, the compiler might apply optimizations that result in totally unpredictable behavior.

This is why proto2 treated unknown enum values on the wire like unknown fields, acting like the field value wasn't even present. This behavior confused a lot of people, hence proto3 switched to forcing the enum to 32 bits. (Note that proto3's approach means that if you have a switch() statement on an enum value it must have a default case otherwise you'll get a warning.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, in proto2 unknown enum values on the wire are treated like unknown fields for security reasons?

Comment: @KostyaBazhanov There is a possible security argument: Recipients are likely to contain switch() statements that cover every expected case but lack a default case. Programmers aren't likely to have thought about what happens in the case of unexpected values, and could easily end up with exploitable bugs. By treating the value as an unknown field, the field's getter now returns the field's default value, which at least is a case that the programmer is likely to have considered and handled. OTOH, proto3 forces you to have a default case; maybe that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

From the protocol buffers documentation:

> During deserialization, unrecognized enum values will be preserved in the message, though how this is represented when the message is deserialized is language-dependent. In languages that support open enum types with values outside the range of specified symbols, such as C++ and Go, the unknown enum value is simply stored as its underlying integer representation.

In c++ an int may be cast to an enum if you *know* that the int represents a valid enum. This is not undefined behaviour, it is a predictable feature of the language.

Note that enums generated by protobuf (at least today) are not of type `enum class`, merely `enum`.

From here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum

And by studying the output of protoc.

Comment: "From the protocol buffers documentation" - link?

Comment: Really? I need to google "protocol buffers documentation" for you? Ok here it is: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum

Comment: I think it's appropriate to add as specific a citation as possible with a direct quote, especially if it can help readers to know the canonical source, and where to look in the future. Especially if someone is just learning about the matter in question (that's what brings many here, after all). Consider adding it to your post.

Comment: I know that it's safe to cast int to enum and I've read the documentation (otherwise I wouldn't know about `EFoo_ARRAYSIZE`). Its unsafe to cast `EFoo_ARRAYSIZE` to `EFoo` because `EFoo_ARRAYSIZE` by its definition is not a valid enum and that is the point where I've got stuck, if it's really unsafe (like in MSVS, GCC and Clang) than I have to change the API to avoid use of `EF_MAX` before replacing good old C++ enum with protobuf enum.

Comment: If you store the enum in a protobuf message, it's a guarantee (see documentation) that the enum is stored as an int. It's therefore valid to store (currently) invalid values in that message as long as you check for validity before using them. TBH though, the design is starting to smell fishy if you don't mind me saying.

Comment: @RichardHodges, Well, this peace of code was written about 15 years ago, it can't smell differently :)

Comment: refactor first, change logic second... the golden rule :-)

Comment: @RichardHodges The fact that the enum values are stored as ints inside of the class doesn't help since Kostya is clearly using the actual enum type elsewhere (and because the accessors cast to the enum type in any case). Under proto3 this is fine since the enum types are forced to 32-bit, but under proto2 enum types will use only as many bits as they need which could indeed lead to undefined behavior for Kostya. I've added my own answer explaining all this.

Comment: Thank you for this. Shame about those sentinel values. Using default in a switch to hide the warning undoes the safety feature of the warning :/